# Constructing a non-degenerate Hermitian inner product on an arbitarary $\mathbb{C}$-vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I was told that the following claim is true: If $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, then there exists a non-degenerate Hermitian inner product $H:V \times V \to \mathbb{C}$. (Perhaps we need to require $V$ to be finite-dimensional?) How do I prove this?

In the finite-dimensional case, I suppose I know that $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$, so I can pull the usual Hermitian inner product on  $\mathbb{C}^n$ through this isomorphism after fixing a basis. Is there a more abstract (i.e. basis-independent) way of thinking about this?

Comment: My guess is that you meant to write $H\colon V\times V\longrightarrow\mathbb C$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you, fixed.

Comment: Conserning your ,ain question, my answer is: no, there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inner product exists in the infinite dimensional case, too:

Let $\{b_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a Hamel basis for $V$. For every $x,y \in V$ we have $x = \sum_{i \in S} \alpha_ib_i$ and $y = \sum_{j \in T} \beta_jb_j$ for some finite subsets $S, T \subseteq I$, where $\alpha_i, \beta_j \ne 0$ (the representations of this form are unique). Also set $\alpha_i = 0, \forall i \in T\setminus S$ and $\beta_j = 0, \forall j \in S\setminus T$.

Now it makes sense to define:
$$\langle x, y\rangle = \sum_{k \in S \cup T} \alpha_k\overline{\beta_k}$$

You can check that $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is an inner product on $V$.